# Does a multi-class wild talent gain PSP on each of their classes' level up?

Tags: multi-classing, psionics, adnd-2e, character-advancement

Suppose Zenobia the elven bladesinger was submitted to psionic surgery when she was an infant, and gained a wild power.

As a 1st level elf fighter/mage(bladesinger), she has

> (...) the minimum amount of PSP necessary to use the power once (...) additional PSP to mantain the power four times. (PHBRS05 pg20)

Now, the rules for wild powers state that:

> Afterward, the character receives four additional PSPs every time he gains a new experience level

So, after some adventuring, Zenobia has reached fighter 6/mage 5. Does she gains 20 or 36 PSP for her level ups?

Answer (score 2):

The RAW don't answer this question, AFAIK.

I don't have links to these rules, since there is no official 2e SRD, but the PHB chapter on multiclassing states:

> A multi-class character improves in two or more classes simultaneously, with experience divided equally between each class. [...] Their hit points are the average of all his Hit Dice rolls. [...] Later the character is likely to gain levels in different classes at different times. When this happens, roll the appropriate Hit Die and divide the result by the number of classes the character has (round fractions down, but a Hit Die never yields less than 1 hit point).

I would house-rule that PSPs work the same way HP do.

Each time the character advances in any one class:
$$[Final PSPs]=\frac{[4 base PSP]}{[Num Of Classes]}$$ 
**raise the PSP 4 points divided by the number of classes (rounded down, minimum of 1 PSP).**

So your character would get 2 points each time one of the two classes goes up (four PSP divided by two classes). You have the initial PSPs at first level, plus 10 PSPs gained for levels 2 through 6 as a figher plus 8 PSPs gained for levels 2 through 5 as a mage. So your initial PSPs + 18 gained later.